# Disable two week view in the Mountain Lion Calendar App

Tags: macos, ical, calendar, bug, tweaks

In Lion I enabled the ["Top sekret" debug menu](http://www.cultofmac.com/136008/switch-to-two-week-view-in-ical-os-x-tips/) and checked the box to show 14 days in the weekview. In Lion it worked quite nice.

Now I upgraded to Mountain Lion it doesn't work as nice as it was and I want to change it back to the normal 7 days in a week-view. One problem, I can't enable the debug menu anymore! So I don't know how to change it back.

I already searched the internet, looked in the App bundle etc, but I can't find where Calendar stores this setting. Do you know how to "reset" Mountain Lions calendar to the default setting for the weekview?

---

Just replaced my Calendar.app with the Calendar.app from another Mac, but no luck. So it seems that this preference is saved somewhere else. Hope somebody can point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you, I had set iCal's week view to 14 days using the Debug menu in iCal under Lion before upgrading to Mountain Lion.  However, at least for me, changing the value via `Calendar`>`Preferences...` did not permanently change the setting.  When I restarted Calendar, it *always* reverted to the previous value (in my case, 14 days) if the value was not one of those available from the menu (i.e., 5 or 7).

There is another way to set the number of days shown in week view, and that's to use the following shell command:

```
defaults write com.apple.iCal CalUIDebugDefaultDaysInWeekView 7
```

This works where `Calendar`>`Preferences...` does not, for reasons I don't understand.

The "7" in the command above can be another number, including ones not previously available from Lion iCal's Debug menu, e.g., 10.  However, I find that Mountain Lion's Calendar has a peculiar bug when the value is *not* 5 or 7: in week view, if you have moved the viewed range of dates such that today is not visible, then using `View`>`Go To Today` (or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) does not move the days in the grid to show today.  The title changes to the correct dates, but the days in the grid don't change to the correct range of dates.

(Hat tip to [this posting](http://www.cultofmac.com/187291/show-as-many-or-as-few-days-as-you-like-in-mountain-lion-calendar-os-x-tips/) for pointing out that the numerical value could be anything, not just a value shown in iCal's `Debug` menu.)

Answer (score 3):

Another (and more definite way) to get this fixed:

- Close the Calendar app.
- Edit `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iCal.plist` and REMOVE the following keys:

  - CalUIDebugUseIPadStyleEventLayout
  - last calendar view description
  - IncludeDebugMenu
  - CalUIDebugDefaultDaysInWeekView
- Save and restart Calendar.

You may need XCode or the PList Editor to edit the file (or use `plutil` to convert to text, edit with TextEdit and convert it back to binary).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out! :) Was pretty simple actually. Just go to Calendar > Preferences... and change the value of days in a week to another value. This will make Calendar reset the number of days in a week!

[Full story over here.](http://mathijskadijk.nl/post/29817879946/disable-two-week-view-in-the-mountain-lion-calendar-app)